# Where do I listen for login status in React Native login view?

Tags: react-native

I've written a login component that works great except I can't figure out the proper way to move to the login page when login is successful.

I know it will somehow involve:

```js
if (this.props.user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      // I'm using react-native-navigation. But any implementation of "now go to the home page" would go here.
    }
```

I've tried putting that at the top of my `render` method, which works, but I do get an error/warning (error in the debug console, warning in the simulator) saying "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state."

Makes sense. But I can't conceive of the actual *proper* place to put it.

PS I tried this but it didn't work at all (navigation doesn't occur)

```js
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.props.user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate home after the user logs in. Or are you checking if the user is logged in and if they are redirecting the user home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last method is almost correct

```
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.props.user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

However, you're using this.props, which are the old props before the update. The new props are passed as the first argument to the method. It's also recommended to use **componentWillReceiveProps** over **shouldComponentUpdate** in this particular case as **shouldComponentUpdate** was introduced to prevent the component from updating.

So, this would make something like this:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
    }
  }
```